# WSRequest retry number of times after failure

Tags: scala, request, limit, future

Below is my method:

```
def buildWSRequest(url: String, accessToken: String, wsClient: WSClient)
    : (WSRequest, WSResponse) = {
    import AppImplicits._
    val d1 = new java.util.Date()
    val request: WSRequest = wsClient.url(url)
      .withHeaders("Authorization" -> ("Bearer " + accessToken))
      .withHeaders("Content-type" -> "application/json", "Accept" -> "application/json; charset=utf-8")


    var response: WSResponse = null
    try {
      val future = request.get()

      response = scala.concurrent.Await.result(future, duration)

    } catch {
      case ex: Throwable => throw ex.getCause
    }
    return (request, response)
  }
```

And my calling part is:

```
var response: WSResponse = buildWSRequest("www.sampletest123.com", params.apply("accessToken").asInstanceOf[String], sslClient)._2
```

I wanted to retry `wsRequest`, *n times*, how to do that?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/viktorklang/9414163

Answer (score 1):

**Retry future n times util the future is successful**

```
 def retry[T](future: => Future[T])(retries: Int)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[T] = {
    val promise = Promise[T]()
    try {
      val f = future
      f onSuccess { case result => promise trySuccess result}
      f onFailure { case th =>
        if (retries > 0) promise tryFailure th
        else retry(future)(retries - 1)
      }
    } catch {
      case th: Throwable => promise tryFailure th
    }
    promise.future
  }
```

`retry` takes future code block as call by name parameter and then runs the future. The future computation is retried n number of times until successful.

First a promise is create and a future is returned to the user. Then completion of the promise depends on the user given future. If use given future is successful then it is returned immediately if not it is retried till the retry count is exhausted. Eventually promise is completely either with success or with failure based on number of retries left and if given future is successful. Also One important point to note is that the given future computation may fail. So a try catch block is used to handle the failure.

*The retry method can be used in general with any future.*

*Make these changes to your existing code to exploit retry method*

```
def buildWSRequest(url: String, accessToken: String, wsClient: WSClient): Future[WSReponse] = {
   wsClient.url(url)
      .withHeaders("Authorization" -> ("Bearer " + accessToken))
      .withHeaders("Content-type" -> "application/json", "Accept" -> "application/json; charset=utf-8")
      .get
  }
```

**Usage**

```
val requestFuture: Future[WSRequest] = buildWSRequest(....)
retry(requestFuture)(5)
```

**Nice API using implicit class syntax**

```
implicit class FutureUtils[T](future: => Future[T]) {
    def retry(retries: Int): Future[T] = {
      val promise = Promise[T]()
      try {
        val f = future
        f onSuccess { case result => promise trySuccess result }
        f onFailure { case th =>
          if (retries > 0) promise tryFailure th
          else retry(retries - 1)
        }
      } catch {
        case th: Throwable => promise tryFailure th
      }
      promise.future
    }
  }
```

Using the implicit class you can now use retry function as if its declared inside the Future class/interface instead of passing the future code block as a function parameter.

```
Future(doSomething).retry(10)
```

**General suggestions**

*Do not block*

*Communicate using return types to outside world*